# Learning Dashboard Designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, learning, dashboard-designer-2013, tutorials

In my searching, the resources for figuring out how to create KPIs (and other objects as well) in Dashboard Designer are pretty spotty. Any suggestions of resources for how better to get familiar with Dashboard Designer?

Answer (score 0):

A few posts about the Dashboard Designer below that may be helpful -

[Create Dashboards by using PerformancePoint Services (SharePoint Server 2013)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj571736(v=office.15).aspx) - a series of Dashboards Designer articles at Microsoft TechNet site
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj571736(v=office.15).aspx

[How to create Dashboard using BI in SharePoint 2013](http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2013/07/how-to-create-dashboard-using-bi-in.html) - step-by-step from provisioning a BI Site to using the Dashboard Designer
http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2013/07/how-to-create-dashboard-using-bi-in.html